# my React app does not update during runtime, when I make changes and save. BUT works on my Macbook but not on my Windows PC

Tags: reactjs, windows, powershell, jsx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## **On Windows device:**

When I run `react-scripts start`

In my terminal it says that my "**webpack compiled successfully**".
When I apply new changes to my code and save, the app does not update on runtime with the new changes.

## **On Windows Device**

I have tried this in both powershell and a wsl (ubuntu 18.04) terminal with node v16.19.1

When I run `react-scripts start` my react-app is compiled successfully
But when I implement changes it does not update directly.
When I terminate the terminal and rerun the script
I can see my change, but again does not update on runtime again.

**(No Result)** I have removed my node_modules and redid all my dependencies.

**(No Result)** I have started with ubuntu 22.02 and downgraded to 18.04

**(No Result)** I have downgraded node 18 to 16 too

project is written in .jsx

## On my Macbook and expected result

When I run `react-scripts start` my react-app is compiled successfully
and when I make changes and save, it does update on runtime.

## Question

I would like to know why my react-app does not work on runtime on my Windows device and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a rather simple solution. Turns out I didn't `ctrl + S` my work.  Make sure to turn on `auto save` in the code editor. It compiled my react project after every change I made and displayed those changes on my browser.